# How to select specific input element based on size and type?

Tags: html, css

I have two sets of `input type=text` elements that are styled differently in CSS. For the first set, the length is determined by CSS `width`. For the second set, the size value is used to determine the length of the input box:

```
<input type=text name=name value='Jason Bourne'> /*1st set*/
<input type=text name=cardNumber value='4111111111111111' size=19> /*2nd set*/
```

Without introducing a `class` or `id` attribute, is it possible to style the two sets separately using just `CSS selectors`?

Clarification: size 19 above is just an example. I want to be able to select based on whether the size attribute is set or not, combine with the attribute that type is text.

Comment: It's possible, but it makes more sense to add a class than to select based on `[size="19"]`.

Comment: @thirtydot: it need not be `size=19`. I want to be able to select based on whether size is set or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible - http://jsfiddle.net/geQqG/2/

```
    input[type="text"]{
    color: red;
}

input[size]{
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Can you combine the text and size? I need to select based on the combined attributes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Dipaks answer gave me some inspiration, I tried on fiddle and this is actually what I am looking for:

```
input[type="text"] {
 color: blue;
}

input[type="text"]:not([size]) {
 width: 200px;
 color: red;
}
```